# Is there a way to access global const from the macro in Kick Assembler for C64

Tags: assembly, scope, macros, c64

I have defined a `const` to be used as argument in KickAssembler (C64) macro.
This works:

```
.macro MAZE(start){
  .const WALL = $E0
  MAZE_fill(WALL)
}
```

This does not:

```
.const WALL = $E0
.macro MAZE(start){
    MAZE_fill(WALL)
}
```

So, if symbol is defined within macro, it is recognized during assembly. But if it is
`global`, then it is not.
My motivation is to have global symbols, so there is only one place to change them. 
Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was wrong to use `const`. When using `label`, this works as expected (globally).

```
.label WALL = $E0
.macro MAZE(start){
    MAZE_fill(WALL)
}
```